# Can't save Photoshop document as PSD

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5

I have read up on this issue and am not finding a resolution. I am trying to create a mobile template with the following specs. I've created other files with these same specs before and am able to save as a PSD or other file formats. Photoshop is only giving me options to save as Large Document, TIFF, and Photoshop Raw. I've tried resetting the design workspace to default, double checking the 8bit, etc. It's still giving a popup that mentions files over 30,0000 px may not work in some apps; however, what's over 30,000 about the following? Any advice? Thanks for your help!! [image]

Comment: Uhm...... look closer..... [something is off.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UbdBH.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Your width and height are set to inches and not pixels.  If i recall the cs5 max file size was 2gb for PSD files.  To correct your issue you should change from inches to pixels.